# Clone not working on embeded document in zf2 DoctrineMongoODMModule

Tags: php, mongodb, zend-framework2, doctrine, doctrine-odm

This is my document

```
/** @ODM\Field(type="string") */
private $Name;

/** @ODM\Field(type="string") */
private $NormalizedName;

/** @ODM\EmbedMany(targetDocument="BaselineBudget\Document\BaselineBudgetItems") */
private $BaselineBudgetItems = array();
    private $BaselineBudgetItems = array();
```

My clone code

```
$data = $BaselineBudgetModel->findById($this->project_id, $find, $sort);

if(!empty($data)) {            

    $clone = clone ($data);
}

$this->dm->persist($clone);

$this->dm->flush();
```

Every thing is cloned apart from the EmbedMany subdocument which is BaselineBudgetItems. In normal insert all code is working but when it ried to create clone embedded document is not working.

Comment: I had this problem to clone object once, and I discover this PHP module : https://github.com/myclabs/DeepCopy take a look ;)

Comment: thanks let me try it

Comment: Well I did it with doctrine way - creating clone for each subdocument. Ref: https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/issues/648

Answer (score 0):

For all people who end up here via search or such, since version 1.0.3 ODM will clone all embedded documents for you, please see [1.0.3 release blog post](http://www.doctrine-project.org/2015/11/03/doctrine-mongodb-odm-release-1-0-3.html).